# Find list of Classes used by a Class in java

Tags: java, deserialization, xstream

I am using an xStream whitelist to restrict the packages that can be de-serialized by my application.
To keep this whitelist restrictive enough in this huge project,

I need to find all the classes used by specific classes that are to be de-serialized.

I have tried using the org.reflections, but the scanners don't return all the used classes.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: I don't know org.reflections, but you don't need external libraries: java.lang.Class have accessors on fields and methods, maybe it is enough for your needs.

Comment: There is a difference between classes used by another class (i.e. referenced by its code) and classes you might need to restore the state of an instance of that class. E.g. a class A may invoke a static method on another class B but there are never instances of B in a serialized instance of A. On the contrary, I can easily construct an object with dependencies not statically visible in the code. `java.util.ArrayList` has no dependencies to `javax.swing.JButton`, but I can easily create (and serialize) an `ArrayList` object containing a `JButton` object.